# Display current progress on a ProgressBar

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

I display the following `ProgressBar`:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:max="100"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar_states"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:indeterminateOnly="false"
    android:layout_below="@id/action" />
```

It looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftqvm.png),

[image]
but I wish to display the current progress on the bar itself like such: `42/100`.

How can that be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

See Android documentation [LINK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html)

1) You need define your Progressbar in Activity onCreate(...)
        ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar) findViewBtId(R.id.progress_bar);

 2) to update progress use setProgress(int) method (example)

```
for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
{        
   progress.setProgress(i);
   Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

3) if you want display just 42% use it:

```
progress.setProgress(42);
```

4) However, what is value from such display? Progress usely used combined with AsyncTask doInBackground(), publishProgress() and onProgressUpdate() LOOK [LINK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

5) if you want display 42% by using xml - just define tag `android:progress="42"`

---

UPDATED
- to show progress in animation and in digits at the same time, I've achieved by next code:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        MyTask task = (MyTask) new MyTask().execute();
    }
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask <Void, Integer, Void>
{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
        {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            publishProgress(i);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values)
    {
        progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
        text.setText(progressBar.getProgress() + "/100");
    }
}
```

Comment: I am talking about actually displaying the progress in text. So if the progress is at 50% the bar would be filled in half and have 50% written on it.

Comment: Ok, you want to show a actual digit on ProgressBar? Isn't it more simple to create additional TextView and update it with value from Progressbar? I mean `mTextView.setText(String.ValueOf(progressBar.getProgress()) + "\100");`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach. In the XML file you have the progress bar. Add a TextView under the target progressbar.

```
 <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="290dp"
        android:layout_height= "26dp"
        android:id="@+id/pbarProgreso"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        **android:max="100"**/>
```

You can either set the max of your bar in the xml file or in the declaration of your listener... is your choice. It is very easy to add a TextView under the progress Bar. You can cast the textView inside your onCreate method and set the view with the values of the actual progress and max progress :

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView progressText = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView));
    pbarProgreso = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pbarProgreso);
   //Setting up initial View
    pbarProgreso.setProgress(0);
    progressText.setText(pbarProgreso.getProgress() + "/"
                                 + pbarProgreso.getMax());
}
```

Then, you will have a listener for any event that increases your progress.. let´s suppose a button

```
 increaseProgress_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pbarProgreso.incrementProgressBy(10);
            progressText.setText(pbarProgreso.getProgress()+ "/"
                         + pbarProgreso.getMax()) ;
        }
    }) ;
```

If you want smth more fancy you can check this post [Show numbers in progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080329/show-numbers-in-progressbar) .

In summary from that post, they use the approach I´m using here and they use a library called [Number progress bar](https://github.com/daimajia/NumberProgressBar). It looks pretty nice but I haven´t used it so far.

I hope this helps.